# ToLookup vs. ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I've been using LINQ-to-objects for quite a while, but I just now noticed the `Enumerable.ToLookup` extension method and read its documentation.  I came across it while looking for the quickest way to get a read-only interface to an `IEnumerable<T>`.  It seems to me that appending `.ToLookup( o => o )` onto the enumerable results in a `System.Linq.Lookup` object that can serve the same purpose as a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

So why would I ever create a direct instance of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` again?

Answer (score 3):

A lookup is not, conceptually, the same as a read-only enumerable.  It's more like a dictionary where each key has multiple values, and is used to look up matching values by key.  Calling `ToLookup` enumerates the input fully and builds the lookup.

A `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` would be far less expensive as it merely wraps any `IList<T>`, as well as matching the semantic meaning of a read only interface to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: +1 Great!  But a complete answer should also mention that `ToLookup` does not "wrap" a writable list like `ReadOnlyCollection` does.

Comment: @HappyNomad That was somewhat suggested in my last statement (mention of cost), but I was not very explicit.  Will edit.

Comment: Okay, but enumerating/wrapping is not more expensive in the way you are suggesting compared to otherwise calling ToList() to materialize a LINQ-to-objects query in order to create a `ReadOnlyCollection`.  For the edit I was expecting, notice the word 'writable' in my first comment.

Comment: @HappyNomad ToLookup is still actually more expensive, as it needs to build the groupings, but yes, using `ToList` will potentially minimize the difference.

Comment: Good point.  Anyway, notice that the last statement of `var readOnly = list.ToLookup( o => o ); list.Add( new object() );` has no effect on `readonly`.